# number of Lattice paths from origin to diagonal after removing vertices

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices

i am stuck with the following problem:
consider the quarter plane $\mathbb{N}_0^2$ with vertices $(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}_0^d$ and edges from each vertex $(i,j)$ to $(i+1,j)$ and $(i,j+1)$, i.e. one "right" edge and one "up" edge.

Now you can turn each vertex off or on. How many different possibilites are there such that 
$i\in\{1,2,\ldots,\frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{2}-1\}$ vertices are turned off and there is no path from the origin to the diagonal $(n,k)$ satisfying $n+k=N\in\mathbb{N}$ left?

I figured that with $N=2$ you have $5$ vertices and the number of possibilities turning $i$ vertices off and having no path left is $(0,0,1,6,5,1)$, i.e. turning off none or one there is always a path left, turning two off there is one possibility that no path is left, turning three off there are 6 possibilites and so on.

For $N=3$ there are 9 vertices and I calculated the number as $(0,0,1,10,45,x,76,36,9,1)$ where x is unknown. So it seems that the corresponding coefficients of the pascal triangle are added up, i.e. 1,9,36.

However, I am not experienced in combinatorics and have no clue how to get a general formula. It would help me if you point out some literature dealing with this kind of setting! Thank you

Comment: For n=3, I find (0,0,1,10,*47*,86,76,36,9,1) and for n=4 that becomes (0,0,1,15,107,486,1322,2228,2462,1862,985,364,91,14,1); no hit in OEIS that I can find.

Comment: Hm ok maybe I enumerated wrong. However, I do not recognize the pattern to prove a general formula.

Comment: If I plot the number of paths to the diagonal (and not only the configurations such that this count is zero) then this plot is quite irregular. That doesn't bode well for any general formula.